# Create an initial loading screen for PSK to improve first paint

Tags: polymer, polymer-starter-kit

Is it possible to create an initial loading screen (i.e. spinner) for PSK to improve the first paint before `<my-app>` is ready/loaded? That will at least inform the user that the apps is loading rather than having an empty page (i.e. slow first paint)

Sample code would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

You can add to `index.html` file simple HTML/CSS preloaders like [these](http://freefrontend.com/css-loaders/). It should animate until `DOMContentLoaded` event. And on `DOMContentLoaded` you can remove that preloader or set `display:none` on that.

Comment: Can give an exact working example on PSK? I have tried similar approach, but it doesn't seem to improve the first paint (which is my goal)

Answer (score 0):

Inside your index.html is your main-component

```
<my-app></my-app>
```

Everything you put between this Tags will be discarded when the component has loaded and is painted..

so just do something like this:

```
<my-app> <h1>HELLO THIS IS THE LOADING SCREEN</h1> </my-app>
```

Of course it is better to put some divs instead of the h1 and style them like your basic UI components( maybe your toolbar and so on) + you can add fancy spinner animation inside... it just works great.